# Best way to parse and validate a fix length message

Tags: validation, parsing

Hi I have a fix length message to be parsed and validated and then send it through a Map. I want to get an opinion on this approach and need to know if there are any other better ways to do so.

Eg. code is in pseudo

```
String input = "12345AmilaJayat21122012";
int split = {5,10,8};
int dataType = {1,2,3};//1=number,2=string,3=date DDMMYYYY

public void parseValidate(){
  loop split.size{
    String data = input.subString(0,split[i]);
    boolean validated = validateData(data,dataType[i]);//This method would vaidate data accordingly
    if(validated){
      input = input.subString(split[i]);
      //add to map
    }else{
      //Error message
      break;
    }

  }
}
```

This is my basic thought, what would be the improvements to this idea and if there are any other ways to parse and validate fix length messages, what would be they?

PS. I checked Apache Camel: Bindy, apparently it doesn't suit my needs.

Comment: I  think you missed one line
"Eg. code is in pseudo" :D... 
I know this is not exactly a pseudo code but I would be writing this in Java that is why it has many Java syntax. I directly typed all the code here. If you need I can edit this with real Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the message has fixed size (or at least clearly demarked) subfields, it is probably clearest (most maintainable) to break it apart into the individual subfields, and validate each subfield by any appropriate method.

If you process enormous amounts of such messages, so that speed is an issue, and the constraints are relatively simple (e.g, this field contains something like MM/YY/DD), you might consider using a lexer and expressing your constraint(s) as a long series of regular expressions.  Most lexers will let you add code to be executed if the regexp for a token matches; if you have a field validation predicate that cannot be expressed solely in terms of shape (e.g., a regexp), you can attach the "rest" of predicate to this action, so it is only called if the field has the right syntax.

Comment: Yes message has a fixed size and there will be only 1 message at a time. And thinking of validating fields through regex.